# How do I use the user value set in the in QDateEdit widget in another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qdateedit

I'm building a GUI using PyQT5 for some scripts I run which requires a user date input.

I've managed to get to a point where I can select a date using the DateEdit range, and have new date printed to the console every time the user changes it.

What I need to do is use whatever date is in the QDateEdit widget in a function when I click the Run button.

Here's my sample code

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QDate
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QGridLayout, QGroupBox,
        QMenu, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QFrame, QDateEdit)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.resize(400, 300)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.group1(), 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)



    def group1(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Box 1")

        date = QDate.currentDate().addDays(-1)
        dateSelect = QDateEdit()
        dateSelect.setDate(date)
        dateSelect.dateChanged.connect(self.onDateChanged)

        checkbox1 = QCheckBox("Task 1")
        checkbox2 = QCheckBox("Task 2")
        checkbox3 = QCheckBox("Task 3")

        button1 = QPushButton('Run')
        button1.setMaximumWidth(75)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_onClicked)

        button2 = QPushButton('Run')
        button2.setMaximumWidth(75)

        separatorLine = QFrame()
        separatorLine.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        separatorLine.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(dateSelect)
        vbox.addWidget(checkbox1)
        vbox.addWidget(checkbox2)
        vbox.addWidget(button1)
        vbox.addWidget(separatorLine)
        vbox.addWidget(checkbox3)
        vbox.addWidget(button2)
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        groupBox.setLayout(vbox)

        return groupBox


    def btn1_onClicked(self, ):
        date = onDateChanged()


    def onDateChanged(self,newDate):
        date = newDate.toString('yyyy-MM-dd')
        print(date)
        return date


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clock = Window()
    clock.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QDateEdit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdateedit.html) notifies the change of the date through the [`dateChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#dateChanged) signal, but in your case you do not want the notification but the current date and for this you must use the [`date()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#date) method.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QCheckBox,
    QGridLayout,
    QGroupBox,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QFrame,
    QDateEdit,
)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("logo.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.resize(400, 300)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.group1(), 0, 0)

    def group1(self):
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Box 1")

        date = QDate.currentDate().addDays(-1)
        self.dateSelect = QDateEdit()
        self.dateSelect.setDate(date)
        self.dateSelect.dateChanged.connect(self.onDateChanged)

        checkbox1 = QCheckBox("Task 1")
        checkbox2 = QCheckBox("Task 2")
        checkbox3 = QCheckBox("Task 3")

        button1 = QPushButton("Run")
        button1.setMaximumWidth(75)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_onClicked)

        button2 = QPushButton("Run")
        button2.setMaximumWidth(75)

        separatorLine = QFrame(frameShape=QFrame.HLine, frameShadow=QFrame.Sunken)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.dateSelect)
        vbox.addWidget(checkbox1)
        vbox.addWidget(checkbox2)
        vbox.addWidget(button1)
        vbox.addWidget(separatorLine)
        vbox.addWidget(checkbox3)
        vbox.addWidget(button2)
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        groupBox.setLayout(vbox)

        return groupBox

    def btn1_onClicked(self,):
        print(self.dateSelect.date().toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))

    def onDateChanged(self, newDate):
        date = newDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        print(date)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clock = Window()
    clock.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful.